# Uncaught (in promise) even after wrapping everything with try catch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have using WebSocket API to fetch the data, once I receieve the message I am checking for error, and there is a error I am rejecting the request. However, After rejecting the request I am getting `Uncaught (in promise)`. I have wrapped everthing the in try catche still I am getting this error in console.

Here is my code.

**Service class**

```
class Service {
  static getUser() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // also tried to wrap the entire body with try catch but still got issue
      const messageReceiveCallback = (message) => {
        try {
          const data = JSON.parse(message.data);
          if (data.hasError) {
           // Error happening here
            reject(data);
          } else {
            resolve(data);
          }
        } catch (error) {
           // Erorr didn't reach here
          reject(error);
        } finally {
          derivService.socketConnection.removeEventListener(
            "message",
            messageReceiveCallback
          );
        }
      };

      socketConnection.addEventListener(
        "message",
        messageReceiveCallback
      );
      publicApi.getUser(apiPayload);

    })
  }
}
```

**React Component**

```
const retrieveUser = async () => {
    try {
      await Service.getUser(payload); // without await I see error twice and with await I see error only once
    } catch (e: any) {
      console.log("eee", e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveUser();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Add a `.catch()` to the Promise. Like [`new Promise((resolve, reject) => throw "Something").catch(error => { console.log(error) });`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

Comment: After adding the catch to promise, I still see the error

Comment: try `.catch().then()` instead of `.then().catch()` - do you see same result?

Comment: What is the error-message after the `Uncaught (in promise)`? Is the socket connections failing? Or the call to `publicApi.getUser(...)`? Is this an async method? If so, return it or add `getUser().catch(reject);` and add another catch after the Promise.

Comment: @Christopher: API is giving a response but I am failing it manually. Based on some condition I reject(data) the request

Comment: What does `TradingService.retrieveSymbols` have to do with `Service.getUser`? And what is `publicApi.getUser`?

Answer (score 0):

If that is happening, you are not 'catching' in the right spot.

Remember, Promises are asynchronous. The code isn't actually *executing there* to throw the error. Only the thing which waits for it to finish is there.

Errors are only caught (in try..catch) if you are using `await`

```
function myPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    thisWillFail();
    resolve();
  })
}

try {
 await myPromise();
}catch(e){
 console.log("Gotcha!", e)
}
```

This works, and catches an error
(Result: `Gotcha! ReferenceError: thisWillFail is not defined`)

If you try that same example using `.then()` instead of `await`, nothing is caught.

```
try {
 myPromise().then(() => {
   console.log("doesn't happen")
 })
}catch(e){
 console.log("doesn't happen", e)
}
```

(Result: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: thisWillFail is not defined`)

Make sure when you `reject()` that it is caught by `myPromise().catch(() => {})`

And make sure you always `reject()` if a Promise cannot complete!

Comment: "*Make sure when you `reject()` that it is caught by `myPromise().catch(() => {})`*" - that sounds like `try`/`catch`+`await` would not work, but it does, as you have shown in the first snippet of your answer.